# Не могу до конца понять как работает delete

Tags: c++

Не могу до конца понять как работает delete. Подскажите что я делаю не так?

```
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    srand(time(NULL));

    int value{}, size{};
    cout << "введите колличество слов : ";
    cin >> size;
    cout << "\n\n";
    char *result = new char;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        int random = rand() % 5 + 5;
        cout << " " << random << "\t";

        for (int j = 0; j <= random; j++)
        {
            value = rand() % 32 + 192;
            if (j == random) result[j] = '\0';
            else
            {
                result[j] = value;
                cout << value << " " << char(value) << "\t";
            }
        }
        cout << "\n\n" << result << "\n\n";
    }

    cout << "\n\n";
    delete[]result;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: К `delete` ваши ошибки никакого отношения не имеют...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: При чем здесь `size`, если доступ потом идет по индексу `j`, который будет от `0` до `rand() % 5 + 5` (т.е. до `9`)?

Comment: @AnT,  притом, что  в коде выделяется память  под один символ, а удаляется массив

Comment: Напишите что именно происходит не так. Уберите из кода пользовательский ввод и пропишите данные напрямую, чтобы отвечающим было легче воспроизвести ошибку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Когда вы выделяете память с помощью new, то возможно выделение памяти либо для одного объекта, либо для массива объектов. Синтаксис создания и удаления разный для этих ситуаций.

В случае создания какого-то одного объекта, синтаксис будет такой:

```
int * p1 = new int;
SomeClass * p2 = new SomeClass;
...
delete p1;
delete p2;
```

В случае создания массива объектов, синтаксис будет такой:

```
int * p1 = new int[amountElements];
SomeClass * p2 = new SomeClass[amountElements];
...
delete[] p1;
delete[] p2;
```

В случае создания массива объектов будьте осторожны, чтобы писать так, как я написал с классом SomeClass, необходимо, чтобы у класса был конструктор по умолчанию, в противном случае создать произвольное количество элементов не получится.

Неправильно вы делаете в своем коде следующее:
Как я понял, переменная random имеет смысл размера слова. И вы случайно генерируете буквы.

В таком случае, вам стоит перенести строчку с объявлением `char * result = new char[random + 1]` (1 для символа конца строки) после `int random = rand()%5 + 5`.

Делать цикл такой: `for(int j = 0; j < random; j++) result[j] = случайная буква;`
А после цикла делать так: `result[random] = '\0'`;
Выводить всю строку: `cout << result;`
А потом делать очистку памяти после цикла по j, но внутри цикла по i так: `delete[] result;`

Answer (score 0):

`char *result = new char;` выделяет один байт, а нужно десять. Может так хотели?
`char *result = new char[10];`